# jQuery selector on an item within an object

Tags: jquery, ajax, filter

I am trying to use a jQuery selector on data I get back from an ajax call.

Here is the code I have -

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'moo.html',
  success: function ( code )
  {
    var divs = $(code).filter(function(){ return $(this).is('div') });     
    console.log( divs ); // gives me back entire object
    console.log( $(divs[0]) ); // gives me the first object

    // console.log( $(divs[0]).('#bar')); // error
    // console.log( $(divs #foo #bar)); // error
    // console.log( $(divs).(#foo #bar)); // error
  }
});
</script>
```

moo.html -

```
<div id='foo'><div id='bar'>123</div></div><div id='biz'><div id='dev'>345</div></div>
```

So how can I grab the html contents (123) of the bar div within the foo div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var bar = $("#bar", $(code)).text();
```

or

```
var bar = $("#bar", $(code)).html();
```

whichever is appropriate.

You can also approach this problem this way:

```
var bar = $(code).find("#bar").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question but I believe this should do the trick: $("#bar").html();